# doing POST - using custom id in JSON Server

Tags: reactjs, json-server

I have a folder and in that folder i have `server.js` which is default from what is available on their website

```js
// server.js
const jsonServer = require('json-server') //1
const server = jsonServer.create()//2
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')//3
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()//4
 
server.use(middlewares) //5

// To handle POST, PUT and PATCH you need to use a body-parser. Using JSON Server's bodyParser
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);
server.use(router) //6
server.listen(5000, () => {//7
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
})
```

In my db.json, there is no "id" but an "employeeid"

i start my json server using command **node server --id employeeid db.json**

When i do a GET, it works. But when i do a POST(sending only fname and lname in the request body but no employeeid as i assume jsonserver must generate employeeid  automatically) i get an error which says "id" not defined.

my `db.json` looks like

```json
 {
  "employees": [
    {
      "employeeid": 1,
      "fname": "manju",
      "lname": "s"
    },
    {
      "employeeid": 2,
      "fname": "albert",
      "lname": "dawson"
    }
```

can anyone please help

Answer (score 2):

The issue I see here is the run command: `node server --id employeeid db.json`

You need to use `json-server` which triggers the command line utility. So something like the following will get you the desired result:

```
$> npx json-server --id employeeid --p 5000 db.json
```

Comment: actually this fixed issue but for some reason rewrite doesn't work if i start the server using above command.  I have raised aseparate question for the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560532/jsonserver-not-redirecting-using-rewriter

Please read the comment i added there as well

Answer (score 1):

**As per doc:** If you need to add authentication, validation, or any behavior, you can use the project as a module in combination with other Express middlewares

Options are not passed when run command `node server --id employeeid db.json`

if you want to change `id` to `employeeid` you can use `router`

```js
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
router.db._.id = 'employeeid';
```

then run `node server.js`