# jsonserver not redirecting using rewriter

Tags: reactjs, json-server

I have an `employees` endpoint with some data in my `db.json`. I'm using node v6.14.9.

My `server.js` looks like this:

```js
// server.js
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()
 
server.use(middlewares)
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter({
  '/api/*': '/$1'
}))
server.use(router)
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
})
```

Server starts on port 3000. If I open **ht​tp://localhost:3000/employees**, it works fine. However, opening **ht​tp://localhost:3000/api/employees** throws error 404 not found. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please debug, I did not found any problem in the code

Comment: @user3921104 what is your version of `json-server`

Comment: ok not sure why. If i start the server using "node server"  then it starts the json server and also supports rewriting. 
However if  use npx json-server --p 5000 db.json  then rewrite is NOT working but normal endpoint works.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles here like I did, there's two ways to start json-server. And depending on how you start json-server will dictate where you put your rewrites:

[Method one (official docs)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#add-custom-routes) is defining your [rewrites](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#rewriter-example) in a `routes.json` file.
Your `routes.json` will look like this:

**routes.json**

```
{
  '/api/*': '/$1'
}
```

and then you can start json-server using the command, assuming both `db.json` and `routes.json` are in the same folder:

```
json-server db.json --routes routes.json
```

[Method two (official docs)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#module) is creating a `server.js` file like the one in your example and you pass a json object with your rewrites to `server.use(jsonServer.rewriter())`:

```
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter(
    //json object with rewrites
));
```

Remember, in `server.js` file, your rewrites must come *before* `server.use(router)`. So like in your example, your rewrites will indeed look like this:

```
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter({
  '/api/*': '/$1'
}));
server.use(router);
```

And then the server will be started with this line in `server.js`:

```
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
});
```

So to start json-server with `server.js` you just use node:

```
node server.js
```

So the thing to note is that when you use Method 1, json-server doesn't know anything about your rewrites in `server.js`.

And likewise when you use Method 2, json-server will not know anything about your rewrites in `routes.json`.
So you have to pick whichever suits your needs best.

Comment: I kind of want to create fake accounts just so I can upvote this more. Saved my a**.

Comment: yvw, glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the api endpoint with a custom middleware:

```js
server.use('api', router);
```

More info on json-server [docs](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#mounting-json-server-on-another-endpoint-example).